# Unit tests: change destination package in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

The Android test project is located on the same level as sources of your project. Now when you create a test class by means of "Create Test" intention the IDE stores it in the sources package despite you tell it to store it in another.

Is it possible to force Intellij IDEA to locate the Test Class into the sub-project of Android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, [feature request in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) would be appreciated.